# 'object' class documentation in python

Tags: python, class, object

I can't find the documentation of the 'object' class in python, which is the root of the inheritance tree of all classes in python.
what I have tried: googling the terms shows pages and pages of results regarding object oriented programming in python.
where can I get the documentation?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=object#object

Comment: You can also get a list of attributes with `help(object)`.

Comment: @Jesper Did you read it? It doesn't say much about the class, like the methods it implements.

Comment: try: dir(object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that `object` is a `class`, and like all other classes you can get two useful things.

- `help`
- `dir`

Try this:

```
>>> help(object) # Will give you some information about the methods implemented
>>> dir(object) # Will give you the attributes list
```

---

Do you want the exact source code?
[image: Builtins.pyi]

I think `object` was implemented at interpreter-level, but in the file `builtins.pyi` you can find something useful too.

Comment: thanks, and i can get the exact implementation of it's methods by googling them directly right @FLAK-ZOSO?

Answer (score 0):

This gives more documentation for each of the methods

[Basic customization](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization)